# How to filter duplicates in a dataframe using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe `df`. `(cfg, x, rounds)` are unique, the rest individually are not.

```
      cfg   x     rounds  score  rewards  
0  f63c2c   a          1   0.01       10  
1  f63c2c   a          2   0.02       15  
2  f63c2c   b          3   0.03       30  
3  f63c2c   b          4   0.04       13  
4  f63c2c   b          5   0.05        8  
5  37fb26   a          1   0.08        8  
6  35442a   a          5   0.19        8  
7  bb8460   b          2   0.05        9
```

I want to filter the dataframe in such a way, that only the `cfg, x, max(rounds)` rows are in the result, i.e.

```
      cfg  x  rounds  score  rewards  
1  f63c2c  a       2   0.02       15  
4  f63c2c  b       5   0.05        8  
5  37fb26  a       1   0.08        8  
6  35442a  a       5   0.19        8  
7  bb8460  b       2   0.05        9
```

For this I identify the maximum using:

```
gf = df.groupby(["cfg", "x"]).max().loc[:,["rounds"]]
```

However, i have not figured out a way to filter on df using gf as a predicate provider. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed possible using `df.groupby` and `df.merge`:

```
n [231]: df.groupby(['cfg', 'x']).rounds\
     ...:             .apply(np.max).reset_index()\
     ...:             .merge(df, on=['cfg', 'x', 'rounds'])
Out[231]: 
      cfg  x  rounds  score  rewards
0  35442a  a       5   0.19        8
1  37fb26  a       1   0.08        8
2  bb8460  b       2   0.05        9
3  f63c2c  a       2   0.02       15
4  f63c2c  b       5   0.05        8
```

And, using `df.sort_values`:

```
In [237]: df.sort_values(by = ['cfg','x', 'rounds'],ascending = [True, True, False])\
            .drop_duplicates(subset = ['cfg', 'x'])
Out[237]: 
      cfg  x  rounds  score  rewards
6  35442a  a       5   0.19        8
5  37fb26  a       1   0.08        8
7  bb8460  b       2   0.05        9
1  f63c2c  a       2   0.02       15
4  f63c2c  b       5   0.05        8
```

---

**Performance**

```
df_test = pd.concat([df] * 100000) # Setup
```

Using `df.merge`:

```
%timeit df_test.sort_values(by = ['cfg','x', 'rounds'],ascending = [True, True, False])
               .drop_duplicates(subset = ['cfg', 'x'])
1 loop, best of 3: 229 ms per loop
```

Using `df.sort_values` and `df.drop_duplicates`:

```
%timeit df_test.groupby(['cfg', 'x']).rounds\
                 .apply(np.max).reset_index()\
                 .merge(df, on=['cfg', 'x', 'rounds'])
10 loops, best of 3: 129 ms ms per loop
```

Comment: shouldnt groupby use `["cfg","x"]` ? If not, why?

Comment: That's a good answer, I wonder why we don't get the same timeit results, but the approach is nicely performed! upvoted

Comment: @ysearka Cheers buddy :) I suppose you've got a beast machine compared to my piddly old laptop.

Comment: currently running performance measurements myself, on ~200k rows. However, the results differ. sort-drop 11k rows, which group-merge has 18k rows. *investigating* How to find the intersection of two dataframes?

Comment: @helt Use the updated solution in my post, because the solution in ysearka's post results in lesser rows.

Comment: ok. timings tell me that group-merge takes 1 sec , while sort-drop only takes 0.1 sec. If I sort ONLY on `rounds` (which should be sufficient when dropping duplicates), its reducing even further. *python 2.7 ?!*

Comment: @helt Hey, it's up to you. The reason sort takes so long is that the sorting is done on 3 columns. If you change that, sure you get faster but your result changes (for the worse, probably). But like I said, it's up to you.

Comment: yw. i was just wondering. btw. If there are additional columns in the dataframe, then the row count of both approaches start diverging...

Answer (score 1):

The solution is not with groupby (or more accurately, the easiest solution is not with gorupby), but with `drop_duplicates`.
By default drop_duplicates keeps the first row of any duplicate value, therfore you can sort your dataframe and then drop the duplicates with the following:

```
gf = df.sort_values(by = 'rounds',ascending = [True,False]).\
                                 drop_duplicates(subset = ['cfg','x'])

    cfg     x   rounds  score   rewards
6   35442a  a   5       0.19    8
5   37fb26  a   1       0.08    8
7   bb8460  b   2       0.05    9
4   f63c2c  b   5       0.05    8
```

You can also equivalently do:

```
gf = df.sort_values(by = 'rounds',ascending = True).\
            drop_duplicates(subset = ['cfg','x'],keep = 'last')
```

**EDIT: Timeit**

Surprisingly I don't get the same timings as coldspeed in his answer:

```
df_test = pd.concat([df] * 100000) 
%timeit df_test.sort_values(by = ['cfg','rounds'],ascending = True).\
        drop_duplicates(subset = ['cfg'],keep = 'last')
%timeit df_test.groupby('cfg').rounds.apply(np.max).reset_index().\
        merge(my_df2, on=['cfg', 'rounds'])

62 ms ± 163 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
70.6 ms ± 28.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

This doesn't appear to depend on the number of cores (I've launched it on 8 and 12 cores yielding the same ranking), nor on the size of the dataframe (I've tried with `df_test` 10 000, 100 000, and 1 000 000 the size of df, and the ranking remains).

So I guess it must depend on your hardware, you will just have to try both methods and see what fits your computer.

Thanks coldspeed for pointing that out

Comment: Yeah!, thanks. DOH. But I think you mean `df.sort_values(by="rounds", ascending=False).drop_duplicates(["cfg","x"])`.

Comment: IIUC you said your data had only uniques couples `('cfg','rounds')`, and you wanted to only keep for all `cfg` value the row with the corresponding max `rounds`, right? Then I don't see why you need `x`

Comment: Updated my answer accordingly.